# Possible to use laravel function inside x-bind:href

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

I am working with Alpine.js and trying to pass `id` in a `href`, I am trying to convert the `id` into encrypted format but it doesn't work, I don't know if we can pass alpine data into laravel method?

I tried this but it doesn't work

```html
<a x-bind:href="/doctor/organization/{{\Maize\Encryptable\Encryption::php()->encrypt('organization.id')}}">
```

`organization.id` is the Alpine data which should be converted into encrypted format.

Answer (score 0):

Alpine is Javascript and is executed on browser side, Maize on the other hand is a PHP package evaluated on server side and it can't access to Alpine data.

Assuming the *id* you want to encrypt comes from the backend, you can inject the organization data from Blade to the Alpine *x-data* or *$store* taking care of passing only the *encrypted id* because the id in plain text would be accessible to everyone

This is one of many possible approaches:

The controller

```php
$organization = Organization::first()->toArray();
$organization['encrypted_id'] = \Maize\Encryptable\Encryption::php()->encrypt($organization['id']);
unset($organization['id']);

return view('the-view', compact('organization'));
```

The view

```html
<a x-bind:href="'/doctor/organization/' + $store.myStore.organization.encripted_id">
  Label
</a>

<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {

    Alpine.store('myStore', {
            organization: {{ Js::from($organization) }}
    })
});
</script>
```